# Apache Nifi PutSplunk and StandardSSLContextService configuration

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, apache-nifi, splunk

I have a flow that puts data in Splunk using the PutSplunk processor. Everything works fine without TLS/SSL.

I now enable encryption by setting the `SSL Context Service` parameter in the PutSplunk processor:

[image]

And configure the `SSL Context Service` as such:
[image]

However, the following errors keep occuring:

```
> 2017-12-12 15:59:58,882 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1]
> o.a.nifi.processors.splunk.PutSplunk
> PutSplunk[id=0771fe32-0160-1000-02c3-222d89687731] Attempted to set
> Socket Send Buffer Size to 1048576 bytes but could only set to
> 212992bytes. You may want to consider changing the Operating System's
> maximum send buffer 2017-12-12 15:59:59,785 ERROR [Timer-Driven
> Process Thread-10] o.a.n.r.io.socket.ssl.SSLSocketChannel
> org.apache.nifi.remote.io.socket.ssl.SSLSocketChannel@7f8b0e2a Failed
> to connect due to {} java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timed out
> reading from socket connected to smi-splunk.sw.goiba.net:10002
>         at org.apache.nifi.remote.io.socket.ssl.SSLSocketChannel.readData(SSLSocketChannel.java:312)
>         at org.apache.nifi.remote.io.socket.ssl.SSLSocketChannel.performHandshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:242)
>         at org.apache.nifi.remote.io.socket.ssl.SSLSocketChannel.connect(SSLSocketChannel.java:163)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.put.sender.SSLSocketChannelSender.open(SSLSocketChannelSender.java:55)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.put.AbstractPutEventProcessor.createSender(AbstractPutEventProcessor.java:313)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processors.splunk.PutSplunk.createSender(PutSplunk.java:126)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.put.AbstractPutEventProcessor.acquireSender(AbstractPutEventProcessor.java:335)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processors.splunk.PutSplunk.onTrigger(PutSplunk.java:149)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1119)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2017-12-12 15:59:59,787 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10]
> o.a.nifi.processors.splunk.PutSplunk
> PutSplunk[id=01601000-fe32-1771-7f5a-76941e62d5e2] No available
> connections, and unable to create a new one, transferring
> StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=95fe41b8-80e3-4120-8003-3693f236c79c,claim=StandardContentClaim
> [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1513093892962-3,
> container=default, section=3], offset=468757,
> length=334],offset=0,name=706764975151967,size=334] to failure:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's
> close_notify: possible truncation attack? javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
> Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible
> truncation attack?
>         at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:1561)
>         at org.apache.nifi.remote.io.socket.ssl.SSLSocketChannel.connect(SSLSocketChannel.java:177)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.put.sender.SSLSocketChannelSender.open(SSLSocketChannelSender.java:55)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.put.AbstractPutEventProcessor.createSender(AbstractPutEventProcessor.java:313)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processors.splunk.PutSplunk.createSender(PutSplunk.java:126)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.put.AbstractPutEventProcessor.acquireSender(AbstractPutEventProcessor.java:335)
>         at org.apache.nifi.processors.splunk.PutSplunk.onTrigger(PutSplunk.java:149)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1119)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could you help me debug what is happening here? We are using Splunk version 7.0.3

Comment: Did you change Splunk so that TCP port 10001 is secured with TLS/SSL?

Comment: Could you tell me where to configure that in Splunk? I see nothing related in the "Data inputs » TCP » 10001 " section.

Comment: FOUND IT! It works now:) However Splunk indexes what it receives as-is, completely encrypted :(